# Can you change the location where windows stores its updates?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update

On my personal home PC I want to change where windows downloads it updates to: `C:\ProgramData\Package Cache`(in folders with long ID numbers).

When installing Python I found that it needs an update ([a windows 10 feature that it can install on older systems - for me windows 7](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2999226)). The Python installer goes ahead and tries to run the update but can fail with security errors unless run as admin - I don't want to have to run as admin, especially since I am installing to a non-system access area on D:\

So my question is, can I get windows to use a different folder so that I don't need to run with full admin rights?

- for example: `D:\myWindowsUpdates`

Comment: If you need Python on your locked down work PC you should ask your IT department to install it for you. Note: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [On-Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @DavidPostill - ok, updated to comply with the rules : )

Answer (score 2):

Use [Link Shell Extension](http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/linkshellextension.html) to link the folder to a different HDD via `Symbolic Link`:

[image]