# Move SoftwareDistribution Windows update folder

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, symbolic-link, hardlink

I have to free some space in my small SSD with Windows 10, can I move SoftwareDistribution  folder of windows updates to another volume using link?
If yes, may I use symbolic, hard or junction?

Comment: stop the WU service, move the folder and [use LSE to link it back](https://superuser.com/a/1105546/174557) (junction or symbolik link). now look if WU works

Comment: does this work or not?

Comment: Yes it works!!!

Comment: Nice to hear this. so both are the same issue and I marked your question as duplicate. There is no need to post 2 time the same answer in 2 questions.