# Set a full drive that only Windows can use

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning, ssd, file-management

I have a 250gb ssd and im looking for a way to lock it so nothing else can go on there only Windows 10 updates temp files etc no downloads, games or media. Basically i dont want that drive to be avalible for me, only Windows.

Comment: You can tell Windows to store its updates elsewhere: https://superuser.com/questions/1105287/can-you-change-the-location-where-windows-stores-its-updates And you can adjust permissions on that location to allow only Windows Update to access this, but the very permissions that allow you to make these changes would allow you to rescind them. So the question is: What is the root problem you're trying to solve? Perhaps if we know that we'd be able to suggest an alternate way to solve it.

Comment: It sounds like that would be ok -***if*** the user only wants to prevent himself from accidentally writing to the drive. If it's really security he's after, he can't have admin rights (and might want to consider Linux ;-)  Hudi, can you expand/explain what you are trying to achieve? If it is just to prevent accidental writing, then music2myear can expand than comment into an answer, which would help others who read this question in future.